# Webpack load module outside the root directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am using Webpack to build my react-redux apps and encountered a situation: 
I tried to take some common components out of one app directory in order to reuse them during multiple react app, but when I tried to load one component outside the app directory I got errors:

```html
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/dev/gdas/WebContent/reactx/common/components/HeaderFooter/Header.js: Unexpected token (74:31)
```

My babel-loader rule in webpack.config.js is as below:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../reactx/common/components')],
    loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

and My import code is as below:

```html
import Header from '../../../reactx/common/components/HeaderFooter/Header.js'
```

Is that any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right. It's just that this file `D:/dev/gdas/WebContent/reactx/common/components/HeaderFooter/Header.js` has a SyntaxError at 74:31

Comment: But the Header.js is compiled successfully without any syntax error while it is in the src directory

Comment: Could you show us the Header.js file? Try to remove the include setting in Webpack.

Comment: Removing the include setting is also tried but still failed

Comment: I tried to add package.json for the reactx/common/components and then add it into dependencies of app, it works